# Can't Connect to NordVPN on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, vpn, nordvpn

I installed NordVPN from the AUR (nordvpn-bin package) around a week or two weeks ago. After installing and getting logged in it worked as it was supposed to. However, after rebooting my computer, every time I try to connect, no matter what server I try to connect to, I get the following message:

```
at 07:44:37 ❯❯❯ nordvpn connect chicago
Connecting to United States #8798 (us8798.nordvpn.com)
Whoops! We couldn't connect you to 'chicago'. Please try again. If the problem persists, contact our customer support.
```

I tried logging out and back in, restarting nordvpnd, and running as sudo. All of my packages are up to date. I'm not sure what else to try. Any ideas?

Comment: I donot know if relevant, but did you try to actually contact support ?

Comment: @Kiwy I did send them an email, however I haven't heard back yet.

Answer (score 0):

Not A solution but works without reboot

```
❯ nordvpn c us
Connecting to United States #8937 (us8937.nordvpn.com)
Whoops! We couldn't connect you to 'us'. Please try again. If the problem persists, contact our customer support.                       /25.5s
❯ nordvpn c
Whoops! Connection failed. Please try again. If the problem persists, contact our customer support.                                      /1.8s
❯ nordvpn set protocol tcp
Protocol is successfully set to 'TCP'.                                                                                                   /0.4s
❯ nordvpn c us
Connecting to United States #8952 (us8952.nordvpn.com)
Whoops! We couldn't connect you to 'us'. Please try again. If the problem persists, contact our customer support.                    /1m-29.4s
❯ nordvpn set technology NordLynx
Technology is successfully set to 'NORDLYNX'.                                                                                            /0.3s
```

Now make sure this is checked

[image]

```
❯ nordvpn c us
Connecting to United States #8953 (us8953.nordvpn.com)
You are connected to United States #8953 (us8953.nordvpn.com)!
```

Comment: https://m.slashdot.org/story/362398

Answer (score 0):

I've got no clue if this is still relevant for you but in case anyone else stumbles upon this post what did it for me was restarting the nordvpn daemon `systemctl restart nordvpnd.service`